# The Facebook Instant Articles module requires the facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php library in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-instant-articles

How about friends, I installed in drupal 7 the module Facebook Instant Articles, but when I activate it it puts me this error: The Facebook Instant Articles module requires the facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php library.

I downloaded the facebook-instant-articles-sdk file from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php, I unzip it and upload it to my site in the path: / httpdocs / sites / all / Libraries / facebook-php-sdk / src return to my site to activate the module but still showing "The Facebook Instant Articles module requires the facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php library, and composer autoloading"

Can you tell me if I'm doing bad lake, or should I do anything else?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have also installed Drupal 7 with fb_instant_article Module.
In addition, I installed Composer_Manager and XAutoload. And I have installed the SDK via Composer.

htdocs/sites/default/files/composer/composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "~2.0",
        "facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "autoloader-suffix": "ComposerManager",
        "vendor-dir": "../../../all/vendor"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\fb_instant_articles\\": [
                "../../../all/modules/fb_instant_articles/src"
            ],
            "Drupal\\fb_instant_articles_display\\": [
                "../../../all/modules/fb_instant_articles/modules/fb_instant_articles_display/src"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dominic, thank for you answer, I could solve it by installing Composer via drush, then I went to modules and I could activate it.